# Spark - Append rows to existing dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file with data as shown below,

```
Id, age, office, designation

1,25, Google, software

2,32, Amazon, associate

3,24, Verizon,tech lead
```

I would like to append header and footer rows as shown below,

```
Google  header info

1,25, Google, software

Footer info

Amazon header info

2,32, Amazon, associate

Footer info

Verizon header info

3,24, Verizon,tech lead

Footer info
```

Is it possible to achieve the above result using spark-scala?

Comment: Hi. Sorry but your question is not understandable. What is the task to complete?

Comment: Hi, need to add header and footer rows to the exting dataframe by using spark-scala, and finally write it into text file. I have tried with println , it's working.iam facing issue while writing into file

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the use-case behind this task.

Here is the solution which will not insert row but modifies the existing rows and prints the output to text file in the mentioned format.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val df = spark.read.textFile("sample.txt")

 df.map { s =>
    s.split(",")(2).trim.toUpperCase match {
      case "GOOGLE" => "Google header info" + "\n" + s + "\n" + "Footer info"
      case "AMAZON" => "Amazon header info" + "\n" + s + "\n" + "Footer info"
      case "VERIZON" => "Verizon header info" + "\n" + s + "\n" + "Footer info"
      case _ => s
    }
  }.write.text("output")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have create a for loop for iterationg each record and added header and footers to each record,because having millions of records

Comment: Val df1 = header_df, val df2 = footer_df                                             for (row <- actual_df.collect){ val dff = df1 "\n" +row+ "\n"+df2}

Comment: Is there any other way to iterationg each row instead of using collect while using for loop?

Comment: df.foreach(// transformation code goes here)  or df.foreachPartition{//...}